# How to conditionally modify a numpy array string with ljust?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

Basically, I have a binary string, suppose `'01111111'` and if the first character is `'0'`, then I will keep it as is. Otherwise, if the first character is `'1'`, then I will set it to `'hi######'`.

However, the issue is that if I try:

```
for x in np.nditer(array, op_flags=['readwrite']):
       if x.ljust(1) == '1':
```

Then it doesn't work because numpy doesn't allow elementwise ljust.

Is there any workaround for this?
Thanks in advance and apologies if I posted this in the wrong place!

Comment: `ljust` is a function for left justification. For example, `'pie'.ljust(4) == 'pie '`. Why are you trying to use ljust at all here? It doesn't seem to be relevant to the task at hand.

Comment: What exactly is `array`?  Dtype, shape?  Sample vales?

Comment: I'm using ljust to find the first character of the string.

Comment: array is a numpy array, Dtype = 'string' for example '01111111'

Comment: `ljust` has nothing to do with finding the first character in a string, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array with strings:

```
In [428]: arr = np.array([ '01111111' , '10101111' , '01011111' , '1111111' ])
```

`np.char` has some functions that apply string methods to elements of such an array:

```
In [449]: np.char.ljust(arr,10)
Out[449]: 
array(['01111111  ', '10101111  ', '01011111  ', '1111111   '], 
      dtype='<U10')
```

including a test method

```
In [430]: np.char.startswith(arr,'1')
Out[430]: array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

which we can use as a mask to selectively replace certain elements:

```
In [433]: arr[np.char.startswith(arr,'1')]='hi#####'
In [434]: arr
Out[434]: 
array(['01111111', 'hi#####', '01011111', 'hi#####'], 
      dtype='<U8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
if str[0] == '1':
    str = "hi######"
print(str)
```

?

Comment: if  str[0] == '1':
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: The above comment has my errro message.